# explicitly storing items in a struct

Tags: c++, qt, struct

I wanted to create a file which has all the KeyPairs I need to use in a program. However, I figured it would be better to have it embedded in the code, so instead, I want to put it in a struct. For example, how do I put this items explicitly in a struct?

```
 {Qt::Key_0, "Win1"},
 {Qt::Key_1, "Win2"},
 {Qt::Key_2, "Win3"},
 {Qt::Key_3, "Win4"},
 {Qt::Key_4, "Win5"},
 {Qt::Key_5, "Win6"},
 {Qt::Key_6, "Win1"},
 {Qt::Key_7, "Win7"},
 {Qt::Key_8, "Win3"},
 {Qt::Key_9, "Win5"}
```

***how do I access these items too?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the struct, and initialize it:

```
const struct
{
  Qt::Key mKey;
  const char* mKeyName;
} key_names[] = {
 {Qt::Key_0, "Win1"},
 {Qt::Key_1, "Win2"},
 {Qt::Key_2, "Win3"},
 {Qt::Key_3, "Win4"},
 {Qt::Key_4, "Win5"},
 {Qt::Key_5, "Win6"},
 {Qt::Key_6, "Win1"},
 {Qt::Key_7, "Win7"},
 {Qt::Key_8, "Win3"},
 {Qt::Key_9, "Win5"}
};
```

Here, I've assumed that the `Qt::Key_0` and so on values are values of the type [Key enumeration](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.0/qt.html#Key-enum), which seems reasonable given your usage. If you need to refer to the struct type itself somewhere, you need to give it a struct tag (=class name, in C++) too; I omitted that for brevity.

Access is like for any other array:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof key_names / sizeof *key_names; i++)
{
  printf("the key value %u is mapped to the name '%s'\n",
      (unsigned int) key_names[i].mKey,
      key_names[i].mKeyName);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it would help much, but if this array is used in a function scope then maybe it would be beneficial to make it `static`.

Comment: @Owen: like you would any other array.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...

***option 1:***

```
struct myPair
{
   Qt::Key k;
   QString s; 
};

myPair mykeys[] = {{Qt::Key1, "Hello"}, {Qt::Key2, "Blah"}, etc};
```

***option 2:***

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <map>
using namespace boost::assign

std::map<Qt::Key, Qstring> myMap;

int main()
{
   myMap += (key1, val1)(key2, val2)(etc);
}
```

***option 3:***

Just take whichever data structure you want (I am voting for a std::map) and manually insert the entries in some Init() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can (almost) use that chunk of code as an array initializer.